# i want to run php function at back end after every 3 sec and update some values in db and this function not disturb other functions executions

Tags: php, multithreading, cron, sleep

main function that run every 3 sec and update value in db
function 1

```
public function set_cron_value() {
    for($i=1; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $this->db->query('UPDATE users SET pass_change_flag = (pass_change_flag + 1) WHERE u_id = 123');
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

this function return the db data
function 2

```
public function get_cron_value() {
    echo $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = 123')->row()->pass_change_flag;    
}
```

when function 1 is running function 2 halt and did't return any thing until function 1 execution completed is there any solution that function 1 execution did not effect other functions execution

i am using php frame work codeigniter

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
// NOT TESTET, just to show concept.
function Reorder()
{
    // query to get all id's, ordered by priority ASC.
    $things = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY priority ASC");
    // iterate thru all items, and give each a new priority
    $priority = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($things))
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET priority = ".$priority." WHERE id = ".$row['id']);
        // add 1 to $priority, then the next item will have a higher priority of 1.
        $priority++;
    }
}
```

That's for reordering your functions, and then you can just have one function move to the top and one to the bottom :

```
// NOT TESTET, just to show concept
function MoveToTop($id)
{
    // get the priority of the item, and the max priority available
    $item = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT priority, MAX(priority) AS max_priority FROM table WHERE id = ".$id));
    // move all items above the current item, one prioroty down.
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET priority = priority - 1 WHERE priority >= ". $item['priority']);
    // set priority of the current item to the max priority
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET priority = ".$item['max_priority']." WHERE id = ".$id);
    // Reorder() could be called here, to make absolutely sure everything is in order...
}

// NOT TESTET, just to show concept
function MoveToBottom($id)
{
    // get the priority of the item.
    $item = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT priority FROM table WHERE id = ".$id));
    // move all items below the current item, one priority up (to make room)
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE priority <= ". $item['priority']);
    // position the current item at priority 0 (zero)
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET priority = 0 WHERE id = ".$id);
    // Reorder() could be called here, to make absolutely sure everything is in order...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a script with intervals you can schedule a CRON JOB. This will be the best solution for running script after your specified time.

It depends on your server hosting you can schedule mulitple CRON JOBS from cpanel of your website.

Comment: for creating CRON JOB using cPanel check this link : https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2198/~/setting-up-cron-jobs-in-cpanel